# Creating a dictionary for each day of the week in a calendar on Excel

Tags: excel, dictionary, calendar, openpyxl

My excel file contains days of the week repeated a few times on row 1 stretching from column A to AL. So Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday.... etc.

It resembles a calendar but imagine reading it horizontally. I'm only in the early stages of preparing the code as I have yet to add what each date plays out so a Tuesday 1st won't be the same as a Tuesday 8th.

For now I've run into a problem already in the beginning stages. Here is my code:

```
                import openpyxl
            import os
            os.chdir('C:\Python27\My files\work')
            Week = {'Monday':'File1','Tuesday':'File2','Wednesday':'File3'}

            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Calendar.xlsx')
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Report planning')
            ws = wb.active


            for colNum in ws.iter_rows('A1:AL1'):
                    dtrmnt = sheet.cell(column=colNum,row=1).value
                    if dtrmnt in Week:
                        sheet.cell(column=colNum, row=19).value = Week[dtrmnt]

            wb.save('updatedcalendar.xlsx')
```

My error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/My files/work/calendar.py", line 16, in <module>
    wb.save('updatedcalendar.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 263, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 239, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 222, in save
    self.write_data(archive, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 80, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 163, in _write_worksheets
    xml = sheet._write(self.workbook.shared_strings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 776, in _write
    return write_worksheet(self, shared_strings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 198, in write_worksheet
    dim = Element('dimension', {'ref': '%s' % worksheet.calculate_dimension()})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 420, in calculate_dimension
    get_column_letter(max_col), max_row
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\__init__.py", line 101, in get_column_letter
    raise ValueError("Invalid column index {0}".format(idx))
ValueError: Invalid column index (<Cell Report planning.A1>, <Cell Report planning.B1>, <Cell Report planning.C1>, <Cell Report planning.D1>, <Cell Report planning.E1>, <Cell Report planning.F1>, <Cell Report planning.G1>, <Cell Report planning.H1>, <Cell Report planning.I1>, <Cell Report planning.J1>, <Cell Report planning.K1>, <Cell Report planning.L1>, <Cell Report planning.M1>, <Cell Report planning.N1>, <Cell Report planning.O1>, <Cell Report planning.P1>, <Cell Report planning.Q1>, <Cell Report planning.R1>, <Cell Report planning.S1>, <Cell Report planning.T1>, <Cell Report planning.U1>, <Cell Report planning.V1>, <Cell Report planning.W1>, <Cell Report planning.X1>, <Cell Report planning.Y1>, <Cell Report planning.Z1>, <Cell Report planning.AA1>, <Cell Report planning.AB1>, <Cell Report planning.AC1>, <Cell Report planning.AD1>, <Cell Report planning.AE1>, <Cell Report planning.AF1>, <Cell Report planning.AG1>, <Cell Report planning.AH1>, <Cell Report planning.AI1>, <Cell Report planning.AJ1>, <Cell Report planning.AK1>, <Cell Report planning.AL1>)
```

I'm quite new and computer programming isn't my best skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are passing in a whole row as a column index. `ws.iter_rows()` always returns rows of cells. It's not clear which column you want to write to but the form should be something like `sheet.cell(column=1, row=1)`